# Array gets swapped before swap function is used

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple swap function, where the elements of an array get swapped once. The idea is I want to swap it once and check if it is the same as the unswapped array (which it will be for some cases, when all the elements are same, or something like that)

```
def swap(arr, pos):
    if pos <= len(arr) - 1 and num != 0:
        arr[pos], arr[pos + 1] = arr[pos + 1], arr[pos]
    else:
        pass
    return arr

some = [1,2,3,4]
#print(some)
for i in range(len(some) - 1):
    arr0 = some
    arr1 = swap(some, i)
    print(arr0, arr1)
```

And the output for this is:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4] [2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 4] [2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1] [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

And I'm expecting something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 1, 3, 4]
...
```

Why does the ***arr0*** array get swapped?

Comment: Because `arr0` and `arr1` refer to the same list.

Comment: What is the `num` variable in your function?

Comment: That was from a previous part of the code, and is entirely inconsequential now. I forgot to delete it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr0 = some[:]
```

this should help you, it will copy the instance of the array not the location of it because when you make change to your *some* this will effect every array that is a directional copy of it

Answer (score 0):

use copy() method.

`arr0 = some.copy()`

Code:

```py
def swap(arr, pos):
    if pos <= len(arr) - 1  and num != 0:
        arr[pos], arr[pos + 1] = arr[pos + 1], arr[pos]
    else:
        pass
    return arr

some = [1,2,3,4]
#print(some)
for i in range(len(some) - 1):
    arr0 = some.copy()
    arr1 = swap(some, i)
    print(arr0, arr1)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 3, 4] [2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 4] [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have made it clear. I just want to say, why not write

```py
def swap(arr, pos):
    if pos <= len(arr) - 1  andpos < 0:
        arr[pos], arr[pos + 1] = arr[pos + 1], arr[pos]
    else:
        pass
    return arr

some = [1,2,3,4]
#print(some)
for i in range(len(some) - 1):
    print("before swap: ", some)
    swap(some, i)
    print("after swap: ", some)
```

Then you do not need to copy the list. Just print swap log in two lines.